# How can i make page links which don't redirect

Tags: mediawiki

In Mediawiki i can create a local page by using `[[link]]`. if that page has `#REDIRECT [[landing page]]` it'll automatically go to the landing page.

I was thinking of creating a page which lists the landing pages and all the redirection to it so i have an easy access to when i may need to change a redirection and in case if i forget one.

I know in the URL there is a `redirect=no` argument so i can go to redirection pages and change them and if i use an external url i can add the redirect argument in however this would mean inserting the full URL which could be a problem when i develop on a local WAMP server where the url is `http://localhost`

so i am wondering, is there a way i can create local pages (`[[page]]`) that wont do any redirection similar to using `redirect=no` in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [ParseFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) enabled (i.e. `wfLoadExtension( 'ParserFunctions' );` in your `LocalSettings.php`, if running a recent version of MediaWiki), you can write something like this, to make sure the external url is always correct:

```
{{canonicalurl:PAGENAME|redirect=no}}
```

This will create a ur like `https://localhost/w/index.php?title=PAGENAME&redirect=no`. Unlike `{{fullurl}}`, `{{canonicalurl}}` will use an explicit protocol (http or https), making sure that you get an address that will work in your local development environment.

I suggest you create a template with something like this:

```
[{{canonicalurl:{{{1}}}|redirect=no}} {{{2|{{{1}}}}}}]
```

Then you can just call `{{templateName|PAGENAME}}` or `{{templateName|PAGENAME|TEXT}}` when you want to link to PAGENAME without redirecting, without having to worry about different domain names.

**Further reading:**

- [Help:Magic words](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_data) (mediawiki.org)